# validate dropdown if checkbox checked inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAttributes" runat="server" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableModelValidation="True" 
              CssClass="GridViewStyle" onrowdatabound="gvAttributes_RowDataBound">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxAttributescheck" runat="server" Text=''
        <%# Eval("AttributeName") %> AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cbxAttributescheck_CheckedChanged"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAttributeValue" runat="server" Value=''
        <%# Eval("AttributeID") %>' />
        <asp:Label ID="lblDelete" runat="server" Text=''
          <%# Eval("AttributeID") %>'   Visible="false"></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data Type" >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAttributesDataType" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAttributeType" runat="server" 
                                    ErrorMessage="*"  Enabled="false" 
                                    ControlToValidate="ddlAttributesDataType" InitialValue="0">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Allow Nulls" >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxAttributesisnull" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void cbxAttributescheck_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)sender;
    string CurrentCbxId = ((CheckBox)sender).ClientID;
    foreach (GridViewRow Row in gvAttributes.Rows)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)Row.FindControl("cbxAttributescheck")).ClientID.Equals(CurrentCbxId) && cbx.Checked)
        {
            RequiredFieldValidator rfvAttributeType = (RequiredFieldValidator)Row.FindControl("rfvAttributeType");
            rfvAttributeType.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have took grid view as above I want to enable the required field validator for drop down when check box is checked. I want to do this server side not through JavaScript.  I tried but unable to work out. I tried to enable the validator when check box checked else it will be disabled. I need assistance on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modified the check box changed event and assigned validation group to the check box and drop down list.

```
protected void cbxAttributescheck_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)sender;
        string CurrentCbxId = ((CheckBox)sender).ClientID;
        foreach (GridViewRow Row in gvAttributes.Rows)
        {
            RequiredFieldValidator rfvAttributeType = (RequiredFieldValidator)Row.FindControl("rfvAttributeType");
            if (((CheckBox)Row.FindControl("cbxAttributescheck")).ClientID.Equals(CurrentCbxId))
            {
                rfvAttributeType.Enabled = cbx.Checked;
            }            
        }
    }
```